# PHP - é possível fazer um INSERT INTO com variáveis php e mais SELECT?

Tags: php, mysql

Eu preciso pegar informações de outra tabela e acrescentar em outra tabela  com mais informações de uma variável php
Eu andei pesquisando e umas faz formas que encontrei foi:

```
INSERT INTO tabProdutos ( id, descricao, unidade, qtd, valor) VALUES (‘$id’, ‘
(SELECT cod, descricao, unidade, qtd, valor FROM tabInfoProd WHERE cod = $cod ’);
```

Mas nada ocorreu

O que pode estar de errado?
Obrigado.

Comment: Sua query funciona testando direto no banco?

Comment: Sim é possível mas essa sintaxe não parece correta. aquele `$id` depois de `VALUES` está sobrando no select.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seu número de argumentos declarado em values está incorreto, tente algo como:

```
INSERT INTO tabProdutos ( id, descricao, unidade, qtd, valor) VALUES (
SELECT cod, descricao, unidade, qtd, valor FROM tabInfoProd WHERE cod = '$cod' );
```

ou

```
INSERT INTO tabProdutos ( id, descricao, unidade, qtd, valor) VALUES (
SELECT '$id', descricao, unidade, qtd, valor FROM tabInfoProd WHERE cod = '$cod');
```

Comment: Oi obrigado, mas está aparecendo o erro 1241: operand should contain 1 column

Comment: certo, remova os parenteses do select

Comment: editei a resposta, depois disso deve funcionar

Comment: Caso não funcione, tente   _INSERT INTO tabProdutos ( id, descricao, unidade, qtd, valor) 
SELECT '$id', descricao, unidade, qtd, valor FROM tabInfoProd WHERE cod = '$cod';_

Comment: Funcionou era só retirar os parenteses, valeu